# Why "Failed to execute 'delete' on 'Cache': Illegal invocation" when cachel.delete is assigned to variable?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, browser-cache

I'm trying to pass `cache.delete` native function as an argument in order to make my code more easily testable.

But when I do this:

```js
const cacheDeleteFunction = cache.delete;
await cacheDeleteFunction(request);
```

it fails with `Failed to execute 'delete' on 'Cache': Illegal invocation` error.

Same code, but with a direct call to `await cache.delete(request)` works.

Also, if I do this:

```js
const cacheDeleteFunction = (x) => cache.delete(x);
await cacheDeleteFunction(request);
```

then it also works!

I've tried playing with `.apply()` and `.call()` but they didn't make any difference.

```js
(async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open('1');
    try {
        await cache.add(new Request('?apple'));
        await cache.add(new Request('?google'));
    } catch (e) {}
    const keys = await cache.keys();
    for (const request of keys) {
        if (request.url.includes('apple')) {
            // Failed to execute 'delete' on 'Cache': Illegal invocation
            // const cacheDeleteFunction = cache.delete;
            // await cacheDeleteFunction(request);


            // Works
            await cache.delete(request);

            // Also works
            // const cacheDeleteFunction = (x) => cache.delete(x);
            // await cacheDeleteFunction(request);
        }
    }
})();
```

What am I missing? Why `const cacheDeleteFunction = cache.delete;` doesn't work?

Related issue: https://github.com/noahjohn9259/react-clear-cache/pull/36/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably because the delete function references the "this". So when you get a reference to it without using bind the this would be undefined. so what you need to do is doing:

```
const deleteFunction = cache.delete.bind(cache);
```

Comment: Right, I was trying to bind/call/apply using `this` context instead of using `cache` context, thanks!